# Segmentation fault when calling glDrawElementsInstanced

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

I found that changing glDrawElements to glDrawElementInstanced results in segfault in otherwise valid program. No problem compiling. gdb says that glDrawElementInstanced is what segfaults. Can anyone guess a problem?

Running on x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Part of CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (sph)

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    /usr/nvidia-current
.
)

set(ALL_LIBS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    glfw
    GLEW
)

add_definitions(
    -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
)

target_link_libraries(sph
    ${ALL_LIBS}
)
```

Site of segfault:

```
glDrawElementsInstanced(
            GL_TRIANGLES,
            indices.size(),
            GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,
            (void *)0,
            2
        );
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with your build system. The code that sets up the arrays and does the call is likely more interesting.

Comment: pmr: Not sure if I should write here; That is the only change to the code and if my understanding is right, effect of glDrawElementsInstanced is identical to glDrawElements except executed multiple times. Is there something I'm missing about glDrawElementsInstanced that has to do with setting up arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Did you make sure that you have at least a **OpenGL 3.1** context available?
2. Did you check if the `glDrawElementInstanced` is not **NULL** after loading it via GLEW?

Comment: That is exactly the problem. glDrawElementInstanced is NULL. Thanks for the help!!